# Does any monitoring metrics/events exist for ClickHouse keeper?

Tags: clickhouse

I am considering using ClickHouse keeper to replace zookeeper for data replication. And zookeeper has lots of useful metrics for monitoring/convenient triage. I checked ClickHouse documents and CurrentMetrics/ProfileEvents files but found no similar monitoring data to zk(https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.7.0/zookeeperMonitor.html).
Pls. direct me to the right way, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickHouse-keeper already supports 4-letter commands 'ruok' and 'mntr'

```
# echo 'mntr' | nc localhost 9181
zk_version  v22.2.1.2764-testing-4fab6bec4ec53b66246a055919a4ed4c0610f650
zk_avg_latency  0
zk_max_latency  33
zk_min_latency  0
zk_packets_received 15430936
zk_packets_sent 15430936
zk_num_alive_connections    1
zk_outstanding_requests 0
zk_server_state standalone
zk_znode_count  4272
zk_watch_count  235
zk_ephemerals_count 111
zk_approximate_data_size    781777
zk_open_file_descriptor_count   203
zk_max_file_descriptor_count    18446744073709551615
zk_followers    0
zk_synced_followers 0

echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 9181
imok
```

It is possible to export those in Prometheus format using external tools like https://github.com/dabealu/zookeeper-exporter

Future versions will have embedded Prometheus exporter.

Comment: Yes. But the 4-letter commands is less enough for monitoring purpose(history status view or alerting). The prometheus like metrics should be necessary.

Comment: See https://github.com/dabealu/zookeeper-exporter

Answer (score 0):

They are not implemented yet. There are plans to expose keeper metrics through Prometheus endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Is there any release plan for the metric exposing?

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse Keeper now has support for Prometheus endpoint https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/43087

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be very well documented, but you need to define `prometheus` section in the `clickhouse-keeper` config, e.g. `/etc/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml`:

```
<clickhouse>
 <prometheus>
   <port>9100</port>
   <!-- <endpoint>/metrics</endpoint> (default) -->
 </prometheus>
</clickhouse>
```

See [related pull request](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/43087). Then you should see in logs that a Prometheus endpoint is binded:

```
Application: Listening for Prometheus: http://127.0.0.1:9100
```

Assuming you're running `clickhouse-keeper` >= `22.12.x`, you should be able to get the metrics:

```
curl localhost:9100/metrics
```